# timing issues with jquery scroll event (sometimes works fine and delay sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide some div's animatedly on jquery `scroll()` event. But some timing issues are occuring problem and so the animation gets weird sometimes(or most of the times). While scrolling down it must hide and while scrolling up it must get visible but their timing is not setting properly (delays most of the times), when I scroll down and up **suddenly** its getting a delay for becoming visible again. I want that effect similar to this website : http://www.flipkart.com/ , i.e., smooth coordinated timing effect, but don't know what to do! How can I make it that much coordinated like in that website (mentioned earlier)? 
Check my working code at http://jsfiddle.net/ankur3291/HnS5m/ .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
lastScroll=0;
$(document).scroll(function(){
    st=$(document).scrollTop();
    $(".top").html("<h1>"+st+"</h1>");
    if(st > lastScroll){
        //downward scrolling...
        //$(".strip").animate({top:'-30px'},20);
        $(".top").animate({top:'0px'},100);
        $(".menu").animate({top:'20px'},100);
    }
    else{
        //upward scrolling...
        //$(".strip").animate({top:'0px'},20);
        $(".top").animate({top:'30px'},100);
        $(".menu").animate({top:'130px'},100);
    }
    lastScroll=st;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now I got it!...the `.animate()` function is creating a stack of calls every time the event occurs which needs to be stopped using `stop()` function before each `.animate()` function. The `stop()` function has two parameters (both are false by default), the first parameter is [clearQueue], i.e., if we need to clear the queue (of calls generated) then put true, false otherwise, the second parameter is [jumpToEnd], i.e., while finishing if we need to complete the animation put true, false otherwise. More info at http://api.jquery.com/stop/ .

Check this fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HnS5m/2/).

See the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    lastScroll=0;
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        st=$(document).scrollTop();
        $(".top").html("<h1>"+st+"</h1>");
        if(st > lastScroll & st>100){
            //downward scrolling...
            //$(".strip").animate({top:'-30px'},20);
            $(".top")
                .stop(true,false)    //This needs to be implemented for stack clearing...
                .delay(100)          //for time setting..
                .animate({top:'0px'},100);
            $(".menu")
                .stop(true,false)    //here too...
                .delay(100)
                .animate({top:'20px'},100);
        }
        else{
            //upward scrolling...
            //$(".strip").animate({top:'0px'},20);
            $(".top")
                .stop(true,false)    //here too...
                .delay(100)
                .animate({top:'30px'},100);
            $(".menu")
                .stop(true,false)    //here too...
                .delay(100)
                .animate({top:'130px'},100);
        }
        lastScroll=st;
    });
});
```